# Eclipse -> Texlipse -> Acrobat can not compile because the file always opens before rebuild

Tags: texlipse, acrobat

Path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe`

There are no arguments given when calling AcroRd32.exe.

OnView DDE: `[DocOpen("%fullfile")][FileOpen("%fullfile")]`

OnRebuild DDE: `[DocClose("%fullfile")]`

DDEServer: `AcroviewR11`

This configuration works on other computers and is believed to have worked on the target machine. We ran into a problem where Acrobat Reader actually opens the file on a rebuild, making it impossible to write to it and therefore cancelling the build.

Did the latest Acrobat patch kill some functionality there?
Is there some other feature in eclipse or texlipse i could check?

---

EDIT:

As I hotfix I just setup the predefined viewer "none".
If I run that configuration, the compiler explicitly tells me it can not start Acrobat as a previewer. I hope this is somehow relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using sumatraPDF as a viewer instead of Acrobat.

Sumatra does not keep a lock on the file, and thus re-building should be no problem.

http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html

Comment: My latest update somehow has advertisement content on the rigth side for additional web services - cloud and stuff. So i am actually very inclined to switch.

Comment: I use both still, but I found sumatra perfect for latex projects. Keeping the PDF open while re-compiling is simply awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You should try sandwiching a `DocClose` in between two `DocOpen` commands in the OnView DDE. 
The following works for Texlipse on Window 8 with Acrobat 9.5.5:

OnView DDE: `[DocOpen("%fullfile")][DocClose("%fullfile")][DocOpen("%fullfile")]`

In testing, I saw no noticeable impact on performance, and it functioned exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I'm glad there's a community like this available. It's been really helpful, and I'm happy to be a part of it now.